# Modify data in matlab instance using MLApp and COM, C#

Tags: c#, matlab, com

C# application trying to reshape data in Matlab. In Matlab I need the data to appear **3-dimensional in the matlab instance**. (The code assumes an instance of matlab is running.)

```
public void PassAndResizeInMatlab()
{
    MLApp.MLApp matlab = (MLApp.MLApp)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Matlab.Desktop.Application");
    matlab.Execute("enableservice('AutomationServer',true);");
    var dat = new double[]{1,2,3,4};
    var name = "myexample";
    //matlab does not support passing double[,,] with this function.
    matlab.PutWorkspaceData(name, "base", dat);

    object varargout;
    //this fails
    matlab.Feval("reshape", 1, out varargout, name, new double[]{2,2});
    //works but does not put the value in the matlab instance.
    matlab.Feval("ones", 1, out varargout, 3,4,5); //works
    //works but does not put the value in the matlab instance.
    var output = matlab.Execute("reshape (" + name + ",2,2)");
}
```

Is it possible to modify existing data in matlab at all with COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to set the value in the execute method:

```
matlab.Execute(name + " = reshape (" + name + ",2,2)");
```