# Matlab output to C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a complicated Matlab function which I would not like to re-write in C#. The function returns an array of N double-precision numbers.

Given that I have compiled the function to into a .NET assembly (a .dll file), and that the function's signature goes like [resutls] = myFunc('stringInput'), how can I call my function inside a C# code?

Thanks!

Comment: put the reference to the dll in your `.net` project, then just respect the signature of your function ... have you tried it yourself on a small example?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the steps to do that:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-cc-application-with-matlab-code-1.html

Is necessary have the runtime library installed on the computer that run your code (you can add it when create the .dll package)

Comment: what happens if the link is broken tomorrow? Consider providing code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it, is by adding MLApp as a project reference.
From MATLAB, you need to start the automation service:

```
enableservice('AutomationServer', true);
```

And within C# you can connect to Matlab using.

```
MLApp.DIMLApp matlabInstance = (MLApp.DIMLApp)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Matlab.Desktop.Application");
```

You can then use the interface functions of MLApp to interact. E.g.

```
int a = (int)matlabInstance.GetVariable("variableName", "base");
```

Or even execute stuff. E.g.:

```
matlabInstance.Execute("evalin( 'base' , 'plot( range , dataVector , ''k'');' );");
```

of course you need some error handling, etc. Normal application stuff.
There's a topic about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035378/modify-data-in-matlab-instance-using-mlapp-and-com-c-sharp)